# Android WebView clears content ond form fill

Tags: javascript, android, forms, webview

I am developing an Android app and want to fill a form in a `WebView` automatically using JavaScript.

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('tbBenutzer').value = 'myUser';");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('tbKennwort').value = 'myPwd';");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('form1').submit();");
    }
});
webView.loadUrl(my_url);
```

The website loads fine and I can see it for a short time, but instead of filling the `Input`, it replaces the whole content of the `WebView` with my username. There is nothing else left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but after some research I found out, that if I put all of my `JavaScript` code into an `function` it works.

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementById('tbBenutzer').value='myUser';}) ();");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementById('tbKennwort').value='myPwd';}) ();");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementById('form1').submit();}) ();");
    }
});
webView.loadUrl(my_url);
```